# Access Pis connected on a sub-network from local network

Tags: networking, ethernet, dns, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a cluster of 3 CM4 modules connected via Ethernet (Turing Pi 2 board), all are running 64bit Raspberry Pi OS (Bullseye)

One of the CM4 has wifi (calling it host), the others don't (calling them clients). I'm sharing the connection from the Pi with WiFi to the rest of the cluster, with the following setup:

On the host:

*/etc/dhcpcd.conf*

```
[...]
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
```

wlan0 is configured too, with a static IP

*/etc/dnsmasq.conf*

```
interface=eth0
dhcp-range=192.168.4.8,192.168.4.250,255.255.255.0,12h
```

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
[...]
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
[...]
```

*/etc/rc.local*

```
[...]
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
[...]
```

`[...]` means there is more in the config file but I've left the default.

I can access the clients from the host CM4, the clients are able to connect to the outside network, and the clients have a 192.168.4.xxx IP on eth0. Now I would like to be able to access the clients CM4 from the rest of my local network and not just from the host CM4, how can I manage that ?

Comment: Is the "host" wlan0 address static (or reserved IP in DHCP) and does your router allow you to add static routes? i.e. you could add a route for 192.168.4.0/24 via the wlan0 ip address

Comment: the "host" wlan8 has a static ip, but not sure how I could add a route for 192.168.4.0/24

Comment: that's why I asked "does your router allow you to add static routes" - only you know your router